# shiny server configuration

Tags: r, shiny-server

I'm trying to customize `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` so that I can use `/srv/shiny-server` for common applications to be run by `shiny ID` and users can use their `/home/userID/ShinyApps` to run their `shiny` applications using their `ID`

Here is the configuration file content after updates :

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
#run_as :HOME_USER: shiny;

  server {
     listen 3838;
     location /users {
     run_as :HOME_USER: ;
     user_dirs;
       }
     location /apps {
     run_as shiny;
     site_dir /srv/shiny-server;
     log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;
     directory_index on;
        }
    }
```

When I tried to access a web-page that is placed in `/home/sri/ShinyApps/app1` using the url`http://server1:3838/sri/app1` , I get the `Page Not Found` error.

What am I missing in the config file?

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Comment: Linux machine. I also restarted the shiny server with same result

Comment: Could you fix the Problem? I'm stuggeling with the same issue!